# Expresion regular en java

Tags: java

De la siguiente cadena

```
550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. [H8EUS03HSJ090.uip-EUH03.prod.com] 6598 haer
```

quiero a través de una expresión regular, copiar a partir del primer caracter que no sea un numero.

Conseguí eliminar los caracteres que son números(me sirve también), pero debería ser solos los del comienzo. Utilice la siguiente expresión:

```
list.getReason().replaceAll("[/\\d/]","")
```

Comment: son siempre los mismos numeros? la cadena tiene siempre el mismo formato?

Comment: No, no tiene siempre el mismo formato. La cadena puede comenzar con un número, con 3 o sin números.

Comment: Saludos Sebas, del ejemplo que tienes, ¿podrías agregar cuál es lo que esperas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cree un Test con tu problema no me parece necesario usar expresiones regulares si el fin del problema es obtener tu mensaje de error sin los numeros del principio:

```
    @Test
    public void cadena(){
            String palabra = "550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. [H8EUS03HSJ090.uip-EUH03.prod.com] 6598 haer";
            int idx = 0;
            for (char element : palabra.toCharArray()
             ) {
            //Solo verifica que no sea digito, no se si quieras tambien incluir los puntos o espacios en blanco
            //!Character.isDigit(element) && element != ' ' && element != '.'
            if(!Character.isDigit(element)) {
                break;
            }
            idx++;
        }
            //Ahora tenemos el indice con el cual podemos obtener la subcadena sin los numeros
            System.out.println(palabra.substring(idx));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion subString, para tomar solamente los valores que quieres por ejemplo

```
    String palabra = "550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. [H8EUS03HSJ090.uip-EUH03.prod.com] 6598 haer";

    palabra = palabra.substring(10, palabra.length());

    System.out.println(palabra);
```

Y te imprime lo siguiente

> Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. [H8EUS03HSJ090.uip-EUH03.prod.com] 6598 haer